# Passing the selected Dropdown Value and Name to PHP with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a form to input a football team's fixtures and as inputs i have the Matchday Number, Stadium, Time and so on. My problem is in the Dropdown Menu where i have all the available teams to choose. When saving the form and redirecting to another page which shows the fixtures the TEAM NAME(name) and LOGO(value) which are assigned to the selected dropdown are not being passed to the PHP through AJAX.

**AJAX CALL**

```
//TEAM SELECTED
$('#input_hometeam').change(function(){
         var team_name = $('#input_hometeam').find('option:selected').attr('name');
         alert(team_name);
       });
        
       //TEAM LOGO SELECTED
       $('#input_hometeam').change(function(){
         var team_logo = $('#input_hometeam').find('option:selected').val();
         alert(team_logo);
       });
        
       //ON SUBMIT OF FORM
       $('#submit_btn').on('click', function(){
         $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url:"queries/insertfixture_queries.php",
           data: team_name,
           success: function(data){
             alert(data);
           }
        });
       });
```

**HTML DROPDOWN**

```
<div class="form-group p-3">
    <label for="input_hometeam">Home Team</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="input_hometeam" name="input_hometeam" onchange="document.getElementById('output_home').src = this.value; document.getElementById('input_stadium').value = $(this).find(':selected').data('stadium')">
              <?php
               while ($row = $home_team->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
               {
                  $hometeamlogo = $row['logo'];
                  $hometeamstadium = $row['stadium'];
                  $hometeamname = $row['team_name'];
                  echo "<option name='$hometeamname' value='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode( $hometeamlogo )."' data-stadium='$hometeamstadium'>" . $row['team_name'] . "</option>";
               }
              ?>
      </select>
</div>
<img id="output_home" src="#" width="250" height="250" style="padding:25px; margin:0 auto;" alt="Team Logo">
```

**CALLING VARIABLES IN PHP**

```
$hometeamname = $_POST["team_name"];
$hometeamlogo = $_POST["team_logo"];

<div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" name="submit_btn" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save Fixture</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the markup for the node with the id `#submit_btn`.

Comment: no, that not, but why do you bother that, since your server knows the exact values already and which one was being chosen, should be in `$_POST["input_hometeam"];`

Comment: @AndrewHardiman i updated the question at the bottom

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz that works too but gets the team logo only since the name is stored in `name=`

Comment: Observation: 1) You have all team data in a database. When selecting a team, all you need to pass back to php is that row’s primary key (usually named `id`). 2) You mention a redirect; I don’t see one here, and that’s not how ajax works anyway. 3) Your current ajax only passes `data: team_name`. Why would your script expect `$_POST['team_logo']`?  FWIW I don’t think you’re even getting the name, because the data needs to be sent as an object: `data: {team_name: team_name, team_logo: team_logo}`. (and that being said, you don’t need to send those values anyway; send the row id)